# Interaction between axes equal=true and xmin (and, I guess, xmax)

Tags: pgfplots

I want to shade a region in my plot while using `axes equal=true`. However, part of what I assumed would be shaded is not. This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 

\begin{document}

     \begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
           axis equal=true,
           axis lines=middle,
           axis on top,
           ticks=none, 
           xmin=-3,xmax=3,
           ymin=-3,ymax=3,
           ]
          \addplot[draw=none,fill=gray!20!white] (-3,-3) -- (-1.125,-3) -- (0.375,3) -- (-3,3) -- cycle;
        \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

and this is the output I get

[image]

For some reason the use of `equal axis=true` makes the x-axis extend beyond the `xmin` value, which makes my shaded area to be too small.
However, if I comment out `equal axis=true` instruction, the shaded area looks exactly as I want it (but I need the `equal axis=true` instruction to ensure that the perpendiculars I intend to draw look indeed perpendicular).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pgfplots manual mentions (section 4.10.1 Common Scaling Options, emphasis mine):

> `/pgfplots/axis equal={true,false}`
> Each unit vector is set to the same length while the axis dimensions stay constant. Afterwards, the size ratios for each unit in x and y will be the same.
> **Axis limits will be enlarged** to compensate for the scaling effect.

So indeed the `xmin` setting is not respected. After the examples the manual mentions:

> The configuration `axis equal=true` is actually just a style which sets `unit vector ratio=1 1 1, unit rescale keep size=true`.

Looking up `unit rescale keep size`:

> `/pgfplots/unit rescale keep size=true|false|unless limits declared`
> In the default configuration, pgfplots maintains the original axis dimensions even though unit vector ratio involves different scalings.
> It does so by enlarging the limits.

Setting this to `unless limits declared` prevents the `xmin` change. I am not 100% sure this setting (combined with `unit vector ratio=1 1 1`) actually creates equal axes but it seems to work. Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17} 

\begin{document}

     \begin{figure}
     \centering
     \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ 
           %axis equal=true,
           unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
           unit rescale keep size=unless limits declared,
           axis lines=middle,
           axis on top,
           ticks=none,
           xmin=-3,xmax=3,
           ymin=-3,ymax=3,
           ]
          \addplot[draw=none,fill=gray!20!white] (-3,-3) -- (-1.125,-3) -- (0.375,3) -- (-3,3) -- cycle;
        \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \end{figure}

\end{document}
```